# Rails application, uploading a file to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I need to create a form where users can upload a file, and based on options they input I need to be able to redirect this to the proper Amazon S3 bucket. What's the best tools out there right now to get this done? Is it a mixture of Paperclip and an S3 gem? What has been the most pain free way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) is the newest S3 (and other cloud services) integration tool. It is integrated into Paperclip and can also be used with [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) (another awesome tool uploading and processing).

Answer (score 0):

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is a great way. So is [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).

Here is a list of file-upload gems for Rails: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads